# How to change if from one liner to multiple lines

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm quite new to python and I want to change this piece of code from one line if statement into multiple lines.

**The code:**

```
self.a = -self.ax if self.a <= 0 or self.a >= dd.maxX else self.ax
self.b = -self.bx if self.b <= 0 or self.b >= dd.maxX else self.bx
```

**What I did so far was this:**

```
if self.a <= 0 or self.a >= dd.maxX:
   self.a = -self.ax

if self.b <= 0 or self.b >= dd.maxX:
   self.a = -self.bx
```

but when I add else statment the code doesn't work anymore. How to fix this problem?

Comment: your one line `if` statements did something in the `else` case that you have not accounted for when breaking things out.

Comment: You need to add an `else:` statement.  `self.a` either gets `self.ax` or `-self.ax`, and you're only handling one of those possibilities.  Likewise for `self.b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code assigns a value if the test is true and a different value if the test is not true:

Perhaps this makes it more visible:

```
self.a = (
   -self.ax if self.a <= 0 or self.a >= dd.maxX
   else self.ax
)
```

You need to account for both cases as well:

```
if self.a <= 0 or self.a >= dd.maxX:
   self.a = -self.ax
else:
   self.a = self.ax
```